# Does flowplayer have an option to stop buffering the video hosted in a http server

Tags: http, streaming, buffering, flowplayer

Does any one know weather flowplayer have an option to stop buffering the video hosted in a http server.
I am not using a rtmp or other streaming server.
So does flowplayer support this option???

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#myvideo").flowplayer("/Flash/Flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf", {
            clip:
            {
              url: "http://whatever.flv",
              autoPlay: false,
              autoBuffering: false 
            }
          });
```

Works for me.

(using jQuery, obviously)

Comment: This works fine. But the option i want is to protect my video from being downloaded. When we play the video using flowplayer, it will get bufferred to the server cache and using browser addons we can download the video. Is there an option to avoid caching of video onto the browser ?

Comment: I doubt it.  If that were possible, YouTube would be doing it, and I've never had any problem downloading videos off there.  :-)